# What can I do with the Ender Dragon Egg?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can the Ender Dragon Egg be used in a recipe, or just kept as a decoration in a museum? What's the use of taking it? I don't think that this is specified in the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dragon_Egg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of practical uses, the Dragon Egg has none. It mainly only serves as a rare decoration.
So yes, you could say it might just be a museum exhibit.

Comment: I saw that it says that emits a "light" level of 1. But that is not really light,it's darkness,isn't it so? @Texenox

Comment: Actually, scratch that, it would mean it does emit light, albeit rather faintly.